# How to add a border ("triangled") that allows see image background?

Tags: image, css, background-image

As it's quite difficult to explain, I'll show you an image of what I pretend.

The problem is not the "triangle", but the image background to be shown in that "space" that triangle generates.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another idea with **one** element, multiple background and less of code:

```css
.box {
  padding: 50px 30px;
  text-align: right;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(60deg,transparent 70%,#000 70%,#000 71%,#fff 71%),
    linear-gradient(120deg,transparent 70%,#000 70%,#000 71%,#fff 71%),
    url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069);
  background-position:top right,bottom right,center;
  background-size:600px 50%,600px 50%,cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text here<br> more text
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do it with a curve with your method ? Instead of a "triangle", a curve

Comment: @FlamingMoe i would consider radial-gradient like this : https://jsfiddle.net/f81hsvza/ ;)

Comment: awesome !! you the best !

Comment: i'm sorry, but I'm trying to do the same vertically and I don't find the way :-P

Comment: @FlamingMoe yes i know it's tricky :) you may consider adding another question by showing how did you try to adjust this and where you failed ;) you may get many answers [maybe included one of mine]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach, how to deal with this task. I use pseudo elements **:before** and **:after** with `transform: skewX(deg)` and `border-left`  properties.
Here is code snippet:

```css
.bg-arrow {
display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background:url('http://wallpaperlepi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Stone-And-Star-Wallpaper.jpg') #ddd center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.arrow-shape{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.arrow-shape:before,
.arrow-shape:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

.arrow-shape:before {
  top: 0;
    transform: skewX(15deg) translateX(-30px);
}

.arrow-shape:after {
    transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(-30px);
  bottom: 0;
}

.arrow-shape .text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-arrow">
  <div class="arrow-shape">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```